# How to disable the rollups tables in OpsCenter keyspace?

Tags: datastax, opscenter

We are using DSE 4.8.8 with OpsCenter 5.2.4.  I don't want to collect 1min and 5min metrics.  Here is my cluster config file settings.

```
[cassandra_metrics]
1min_ttl = -1
5min_ttl = -1
2hr_ttl = 7776000
24hr_ttl = 31536000
```

I have the same issue with 4.8.15 DSE.  According to the documentation, TTL value of -1 should disable the metric collection.  I restarted Opscenter.  However, I still see the 1min and 5min metrics being collected.  I even truncated the tables and clear the snapshots to make sure there is no old records.  I check the rollups60 and rollups300 directories and the number of files and size of the files grow over time.  How to disable the Cassandra metrics collection?